# How to stringify regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a following regex which chekcks if input is an email:

```
/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/
```

And I would like to stringify it in javascript. I was trying to use:

```
var regex = new RegExp("/^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/");
regex.toString();
```

but this yields me with the wrong result:

```
/\/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$\//
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `new RegExp("^[_a-z0-9]+(\\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,4})$");`

Comment: The linked "duplicate" answer doesn't seem to have anything to do with stringifying a regular expression in JavaScript.

Also, use `String(/\w/i)` to stringify regular expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/source) property

> The source property returns a String containing the source text of the
>   regexp object, and it doesn't contain the two forward slashes on both
>   sides and any flags.

```js
var regex = /^[_a-z0-9]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/;
snippet.log(regex.source)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's interesting to mention that it's also possible to get the RegExp flags (if any) through the [flags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/flags) property.

Comment: how to reconstruct this regex back from the source?

Comment: For example, like this: 
`const encodeRegExp = (re) => JSON.stringify([ re.source, re.flags ]); const decodeRegExp = (json) => new RegExp(...JSON.parse(json)); const re = /^Hello (\p{L}+)/ui; const asStr = encodeRegExp(re); const asReAgain = decodeRegExp(asStr);`